# Golang operator sdk tool (operator-sdk) run in wsl and cannot upload the image on hub.docker.com

Tags: go, operator-sdk

I am trying to build a GO Operator.

Because I have not a linux but I have wsl2 (with docker desktop) I tried to install Go Operator SDK on this linux (from wsl2) but I have some issues ... it builds the image but when tries to upload it (on hub.docker.com) seems something goes wrong (please see the attached image)

First I installed golang , git , docker and kubectl inside wsl
In wsl shell I did:

```
1.  mkdir memcached-operator and cd memcached-operator
2.  operator-sdk init --domain hub.docker.com --repo github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk-samples/tree/master/go/memcached-operator
3.  operator-sdk create api --group cache --version v1alpha1 --kind Memcached --resource --controller
```

All goes ok until this step

I made even this check to be sure I can connect ...

docker login -u aurel_sandu_2003@yahoo.com , it goes ok

But when I run
4. make docker-build docker-push IMG="hub.docker.com/memcached-operator:v0.0.1" ... I get this ...

[image]

it is build Ok but it seems it have no right to put the image there .... do you know , there is some restrictions? Because I can connect before .....

Should I do something before upload?

Thanks,
Aurel